# Экспорт раздела реестра в файл

Tags: c#

Как экспортировать определенный раздел из реестра в файл ".reg" ?

P.S: Пока что нашёл статью: [RegSaveKeyEx](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/amourshmuel/2012/02/10/registry-import-amp-export-in-c-regsavekeyex-amp-regrestorekey/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\test");
Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/e " + fileName+" " + reg.ToString());
```

[How to export a registry in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316827/how-to-export-a-registry-in-c-sharp)